# Add anchor point to headers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a really big html-document consisting of a number of `<h4>` headers accompanied by a short `<p>` 'body'.

I need to add an anchor point (is it the correct term, btw?) to each of the headers.

I'm iterating over the headers, and adding them to a menu-ul:

```
headz = document.getElementsByTagName("h4");
arrayOfHeaders=[];

x = 0;
y = headz.length;

$("#menu").html("<ul>")
while (x<y){   
    arrayOfHeaders[x] = "<li><a href='#" + x +"'>" + headz[x].innerText + "</a></li>";
    $("#menu").append(arrayOfHeaders[x])
    x++;
}
$("#menu").append("</ul>")
```

I need a way to attach the anchor points to the headers.

**Edit:** To clarify - what i need is the add a name-tag to each of the -elements.
The first header should be edited from `'<h4>' header'</h4>'` to `'<h4 name="0">'...`

Without editing the html, of course.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "anchor point", as the `a` element, used to link pages is the `anchor` element.

Comment: Each of the h4-headers gets an 'id', i need the links to point to the corresponding header.

Comment: Fine, and what are you having difficulties with, exactly? You haven't posted your markup (even an example of what one of the `<h4>` headers looks like), so it is difficult to help.

Comment: Please use `var` when declaring variables, unless you really think you need them all in the global scope (usually never the case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set ids to the if they do not have one.

```
headz = document.getElementsByTagName("h4");
arrayOfHeaders=[];

x = 0;
y = headz.length;

var str = "<ul>";
while (x<y){
    var elem = headz[x];
    var id = elem.id || "heading_" + x;
    elem.id = id;
    str += "<li><a href='#" + id +"'>" + elem.innerText + "</a></li>";
    x++;
}
$("#menu").append( str + "</ul>");
```

and FYI innerText is not cross browser friendly.

jQuery solution

```
var str = "<ul>";
$("h4").each(
    function(i){
        var id = this.id || "header_" + i;
        this.id=id;
        str += '<li><a href="#' + id + '">' + this.innerHTML + '</a></li>';
    } 
);
str += "</ul>";
$("#menu").append(str);
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Is it better to use innerHTML? Since the headers doesn't contain anything more the header, so to say.

Comment: Yes innerHTML would be better in this case.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `li`s should be appended to the `ul` not `#menu` also `$("#menu").append("</ul>");`?

Comment: Ah, I did not even look at how the OP was coding the menu. Nice eyes @Musa

Answer (score 1):

Since you used jquery already, thought id write it all in it:

```
var html = '<ul>';

$('h4').each(function (index, header) {
    html += '<li><a href="#' + header.id +'">' + header.html() + '</a></li>'; 
});

html += '</ul>';

$('#menu').append(html);
```

Comment: Your code has same issue as the OP posted. You are not fixing the ID issue.

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem

```
headz = document.getElementsByTagName("h4");
arrayOfHeaders=[];

x = 0;
y = headz.length;

var html = "<ul>";
while (x<y){   
   html  += "<li><a href='#" + headz[x].id +"'>" + headz[x].innerText + "</a></li>";       
    x++;
}
$("#meny").append( html + "</ul>")
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is similar to rissicay's answer but I think it's more concise:

```
var html = []; // create an empty array to store iterated html in
// loop over every heading... 
$('h4').each(function(index) {
  // and add it to array previously created
  html.push("<li><a href='#" + index +"'>" + $(this).html() + "</a></li>");
  // add name attribute to heading
  $(this).attr('name', index);
});
// finally, append all to menu together with unordered list
$('#menu').append('<ul>' + html.join() + '</ul>');
```

Basically, try to minimize dom manipulation (.append(), .prepend(), .html()) as much as possible

Answer (score 0):

I think the concept you refer to is sometimes known as an "internal link" - see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) under the second section "HTML Links - The id Attribute".

Now looking at your example code you are clearly using jQuery so why not make the most of it?

```
$("h4").each(function() {
   $("#links").append("<a href='#" + this.id + "'>link to " + this.id + "</a><br /><br />");
});
```

See the following fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/r0k3t/PhrB6/

Hope that helps.